# Scan an application behind Cloudflare and need credentials

Tags: cloudflare, burp

I need to scan my non-Production site with Burp.
The problem is the application is behind Cloudflare and needs credentials to access the application.

I checked the questions and documents but could not find any way forward.

Can you guide me as where to look for it?

My Burp instance does not have a public IP.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Behind Cloudflare and needs credentials" I assume you mean it is behind Cloudflare Zero Trust. If that is the case, then I recommend adding another rule to the Zero Trust configuration that allows your scanner's IP address to pass through Zero Trust without a login.

Comment: My scanner does not have a public IP. It is within the corporate network only.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you need to ask the people in charge of the resource you are trying to scan to open up an internal port or something. This becomes more of an internal network configuration question than a Cloudflare question.